# NextJS API routes not found on apex domain but accessible on www

Tags: javascript, next.js, dns

I need some help understanding an issue I am facing with my NextJS application.

I am using
next@13.2.3 with pages structure.

I have added an API route on my application. I was testing on my staging instance with production environment and noticed that my API routes respond 404 when I use the apex domain mydomain.ext returning this JSON body:

```json
{"message":"Invalid request","code":404,"help":"Invalid request. Please check the docs. ERR: 002"}
```

But the routes are accessible if I use [www.mydomain.ext](http://www.mydomain.ext)
On top of my application, I am using Cloudflare and configured the DNS with the DNS target provided by heroku. SSL certificates are valid.

I want to use the apex domain for convenience because it's shorter. I tried redirecting all requests from [www.mydomain.ext](http://www.mydomain.ext) to mydomain.ext with a 308 status using a middleware:

```js
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const host = req.headers.get('host');
  if (!host) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }
  const wwwRegex = /^www\./;
  if (wwwRegex.test(host) && !host.includes('localhost')) {
    const newHost = host.replace(wwwRegex, '');
    return NextResponse.redirect(`https://${newHost}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, 308);
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

But it doesn't solve the issue with the 404 on the `/api` routes.
Anybody else ran into this issue here?

#### Additional information

```js
{"message":"Invalid request","code":404,"help":"Invalid request. Please check the docs. ERR: 002"}
```